# Embedding a website in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to embed a website into an iframe to post onto my site. But for some reason the site I am trying to embed is not working properly.

Not working (just shows a blank white page):

```
<iframe src="https://embeds.tagboard.com/newFLdriver/337842/" style="width: 100%; height: 5325px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This website works:

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" style="width: 100%; height: 5325px;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But then google would not work either.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Just shows a blank white page ...

Comment: Look in the console to see if there are errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://embeds.tagboard.com/newFLdriver/337842/` is denying embeding in an iframe.

My chrome dev tools console told me:

> Refused to display 'https://embeds.tagboard.com/newFLdriver/337842/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

In addition to that, I'm getting a 404, that might be their behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Some sites do not allow X-Policy. If you check the console you have this error:

Refused to display 'https://embeds.tagboard.com/newFLdriver/337842/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

You can read more on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options):

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a ,  or  . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.